# Horizontal UICollectionViewFlowLayout with vertical Sections

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

How to make layout like that?

It's like UICollectionViewFlowLayout with UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal but with vertical sections.

I know how to do that with tableView of collectionViews, but it's not suitable

```
[==========================<SECTION 0>==========================]

|------------|   |------------|   |------------|   |------------|
|0 0         |   |0 3         |   |0 6         |   |0 9         |
|------------|   |------------|   |------------|   |------------|

|------------|   |------------|   |------------|                 
|0 1         |   |0 4         |   |0 7         |                 
|------------|   |------------|   |------------|                 

|------------|   |------------|   |------------|                 
|0 2         |   |0 5         |   |0 8         |                 
|------------|   |------------|   |------------|                 

[==========================<SECTION 1>==========================]

|------------|   |------------|   |------------|                 
|1 0         |   |1 3         |   |1 6         |                 
|------------|   |------------|   |------------|                 

|------------|   |------------|                                  
|1 1         |   |1 4         |                                  
|------------|   |------------|                                  

|------------|   |------------|                                  
|1 2         |   |1 5         |                                  
|------------|   |------------|                                  

[==========================<SECTION 2>==========================]

|------------|   |------------|   |------------|   |------------|
|2 0         |   |2 2         |   |2 4         |   |2 6         |
|------------|   |------------|   |------------|   |------------|

|------------|   |------------|   |------------|                 
|2 1         |   |2 3         |   |2 5         |                 
|------------|   |------------|   |------------|
```